# Is there a way to "touch" a document in ArangoDb

Tags: arangodb, optimistic-locking, arangojs

I need to be able to "touch" a document (for optimistic purposes) in ArangoDb in order to check and update the _rev without modifying any other data in the document.  I have yet to find a way to do this generically with AQL or Javascript Driver without knowing something about existing data in the document.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Some research and testing points to using AQL like:

```
LET doc = DOCUMENT(@id)
REPLACE doc IN @@collection OPTIONS { ignoreRevs: false, revision: @revision }
```